# Plugin with id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' not found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

In implementing the 'Performance' feature of Firebase, I got the following error attempting to sync the Gradle:

```
Plugin with id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' not found.
```

I implemented it following instructions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android. In particular it directs you to specify the classpath dependency to com.google.firebase:perf-plugin in your root-level (project-level) Gradle file, not he app-level:

[image]

Here are my Gradles, app-level left, project-level right:

[image]

Comment: more than 1 year and the firebase-perf did not update or mentioned anything related to this issue. It is really something bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the red box warning not to put the perf-plugin in the app-level Gradle, putting it there allowed syncing and compiling, but with all sorts of new red warnings in the compile build log:

[image]

[image]

Not including the plugin at all still gave me something in my performance tab a couple weeks after adding just the implementation line:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.9'
```

[image]

The better of these two Performance implementation solutions, to just leave the plugin out vs the gains of adding it to the app-level Gradle, despite apparent dependency conflict risks and build exceptions, I'd be open to views.

Comment: If you don't add the plugin, then it won't do automatic monitoring of HTTP requests as advertised.  So, that's not exactly a "fix".  If you have a problem with the plugin, you should report that to Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 8):

Please add Performance plugin in your dependency class-path

```
`classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin`
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' version '1.4.2' apply false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was helpful for me! Why would it change name when using .kts??

Answer (score 3):

The configurations Firebase gave us to do are the following:

**App Gradle:**
[image]
**Project Gradle:**
[image]

**Solution to fix the problem:**

1. Remove **id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf")** from **plugins section** in **Project Gradle**.
2. Instead, add **classpath("com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2")** to **buildscript/dependencies** in **Project Gradle**, like below:

[image]